# Using Outlook VSTO to customize search bar

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Using c# with VSTO Outlook project, is possible to set values in inbox search box?

I know how to search emails via c# code but i need to show the results in inbox window.

For example set in that box **email from:”teste@teste.com”** via c#

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - call `Application.ActiveExplorer.Search("email from:""teste@teste.com""", 0)`